# Secure database in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-vpc, whitelist

so I have an Elastic Beanstalk running Nodejs that is behind a load balancer. I also have a MYSQL database that is accessed by the Elastic Beanstalk. While I am primary a developer and not much of an IT guy I was asked to make it so the Elastic Beanstalk and the DB run in the same VPC and that the database access be white listed to the IP of the Elastic Beanstalk and the IP of the internal network. Because I don't have much IT experience I am looking for a good tutorial to teach me to do this. Preferably a video tutorial with step by step walk through or if one of you kind souls would walk me through it that would be great. I figure this is a fairly common configuration but I haven't been able to find a good example on the docs. A link to a video or a step by step walk through would be fantastic thanks.

Comment: Seems very similar to this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html

Comment: Its common, but don't mistake it for an `easy` thing to do. You need more info. Puting DB in same VPC may be as simple as putting everything in a deafult vpc, or as complicated as creating and configure your own VPC with private subsets across multiple availability zone.